# Access all the unique data types from my data frame 'data_re' for each column using numpy function unique()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

> The following is my code. I have a excel file 'SOLAR LAKE DATA' which
>   was successfully imported and read in spyder IDE.

```
import os
import numpy
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\91911\Desktop\python_work')
data_re= pd.read_excel('SOLAR LAKE DATA.xlsx',index_col=0)
print(data_re.info())
print(data_re['Dec'])
print(numpy.unique([data_re['Dec']]))
```

Error is in the last line of the code. I thought it might be just of 'object' datatype but For all the columns it returns the same error.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

output for print(data_re.info())

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Float64Index: 32 entries, 1.0 to nan
Data columns (total 17 columns):
Lake Name      31 non-null object
Area           32 non-null object
Jan            30 non-null float64
Feb            30 non-null float64
March          30 non-null float64
April          30 non-null float64
May            30 non-null float64
June           30 non-null float64
July           30 non-null float64
Aug            30 non-null float64
Sept           30 non-null float64
Oct            30 non-null float64
Nov            30 non-null float64
Dec            31 non-null object
Annual         32 non-null float64
Unnamed: 16    0 non-null float64
Unnamed: 17    6 non-null object
dtypes: float64(13), object(4)
memory usage: 4.5+ KB
```

output of print(data_re['Dec'])

```
  Sl.No
    1.0     2.05107e+06
    2.0        22169414
    3.0     1.74372e+06
    4.0     3.99938e+06
    5.0     4.77459e+06
    6.0      3.5255e+06
    7.0     5.27736e+06
    8.0      1.3404e+06
    9.0        38624968
    10.0       52359180
    11.0       10954118
    12.0       18121980
    13.0       24163618
    14.0        5058045
    15.0       16690173
    16.0       13860450
    17.0       18512718
    18.0       14243217
    19.0       12167088
    20.0       22349710
    21.0       33673504
    22.0       63689224
    23.0       70437184
    24.0       38629740
    25.0       70552800
    26.0      134429464
    27.0       64825964
    28.0       33424032
    29.0       53923840
    30.0       50731108
    NaN             NaN
    NaN              MW
    Name: Dec, dtype: object
```

I looked up for similar error but that did not help solve the issue. I am no where comparing float with string anywhere above. Any help would be appreciated

edit 1: Column 'Area'

```
Sl.No
1.0          204973
2.0          437769
3.0          151150
4.0          240080
5.0          131422
6.0          169255
7.0          252211
8.0           64059
9.0         1871443
10.0        2387353
11.0         499460
12.0         824970
13.0        1113168
14.0         241730
15.0         747991
16.0         621174
17.0         885385
18.0         681194
19.0         581901
20.0        1014571
21.0        1593159
22.0        2892627
23.0       3199106 
24.0        1754480
25.0        3204356
26.0        6105497
27.0        3164272
28.0        1556209
29.0        2510672
30.0        2362020
NaN     3.82646e+07
NaN         9455.04
Name: Area, dtype: object
```

Comment: In pandas if there's a string in a column, the dtype is set to `object`.  `np.unique` uses sorting to group like values together.  With a mix of strings and numbers that sort fails.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by missing values on the index try:

```
print(numpy.unique([data_re.loc[data_re.index.dropna()]['Dec']]))
```

Comment: it worked. Now I understand that since indexing of last two value is missing, the function fails. But why has it not been indexed? Does it only index when the value are not missing?  I tried removing 'index_col=0' and running the program again, it indexed till the end in the index column. But the problem persist with 'Area' column. I've attached the column details in the question.

Comment: Also, why is the data type object if all it has are numbers?

Comment: if you look closely:
    23.0       3199106

There is a space after 3199106, making it a string...